# SwiftUI - Why is the date format not consistent?

Tags: swift, swiftui, datepicker

I'm using [DatePicker](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/datepicker) and the date format for the days aren't consistent. Some of them appear as "Feb 21, 2022", when some of them appear as "2/22/2022". What could be causing this problem?

[image]
[image]

This is the code I use to generate the date picker:

```
DatePicker("", selection: $selectedDate, displayedComponents: [.date, .hourAndMinute])
        .datePickerStyle(CompactDatePickerStyle())
        .labelsHidden()
        .clipped()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know this was a bug associated with the `datepicker`. Seems that it is still not fixed. There was a workaround for that as follows.

```
DatePicker("", selection: $selectedDate, displayedComponents: [.date, .hourAndMinute])
        .datePickerStyle(CompactDatePickerStyle())
        .labelsHidden()
        .clipped()
        .id(selectedDate)
```

Comment: Works like a charm, thank you! :) I hope they fix this bug soon.